# List of unique characters of a dataset

Tags: python, nlp

I have a dataset in a dataframe and I want to see the total number of characters and the list of unique characters.

As for the total number of characters I have implemented the following code which seems is working well

```
df["Preprocessed_Text"].str.len().sum()
```

Could you please let me know how to get a list with the unique characters (not including the space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from string import ascii_letters

chars = set(''.join(df["Preprocessed_Text"])).intersection(ascii_letters)
```

If you need to work with a different alphabet, then simply replace `ascii_letters` with whatever you need.

If you want every character but the space then:

```
chars = set(''.join(df["Preprocessed_Text"]).replace(' ', ''))
```

Comment: unfortunatelly my texts are not contain latin characters. They are documents with different alphabet.

Comment: @JohnSmith How am I supposed to give you an exhaustive answer if you do not give me all the details? I clearly need to know what alphabet you're working with. Or do you need to count ANY CHARACTER? Like '1', '*', '~'...

Comment: unichars = list(''.join(df["Preprocessed_Text"]))
print(sorted(set(unichars), key=unichars.index))

Comment: I am working on ancient Greek and I mean any character. I implemented the code (see abode) and I think I solved my issue. What do you think?

Comment: @JohnSmith by using your approach you're not getting rid of spaces. See my updated answer instead

Comment: OP wanted "a list with the unique characters (not including the space)". Why are you making assumptions about the characters used?

Answer (score 0):

```
unichars = list(''.join(df["Preprocessed_Text"]))
print(sorted(set(unichars), key=unichars.index))
```

Comment: You're not getting rid of spaces. Also, it's useless to convert the string to a list, just get rid of that operation

Answer (score 0):

```
unique = list(set([letter for letter in ''.join(df['Processed_text'].values) if letter != " "]))
```